# NoClassDefFound Error in this Java Code

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am facing an error in this code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
public void simplebarchart()
{
   DefaultCategoryDataset dataset=new DefaultCategoryDataset() ;  
   dataset.setValue(80, "Marks", "Student1");
   dataset.setValue(70, "Marks", "Student2");
   dataset.setValue(65, "Marks", "Student3");
   dataset.setValue(90, "Marks", "Student4");
   JFreeChart c=ChartFactory.createBarChart("Student Score" ,"Student Name", "Marks",dataset, 
   PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
   CategoryPlot p=c.getCategoryPlot();
   p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
   ChartFrame frame=new ChartFrame("Bar Chart",c);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setSize(450, 350);

}
```

The error is given below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

 org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Which version of jfreechart are you using?

Comment: Please do not put 3 or 4 lines between each line of code..

Answer (score 13):

Do you have jcommon in your classpath?

If not, simply add jCommon to your classpath and your problem should be solved.

Searches on the web suggests this answer frequently.